# Defining a rule of inference using infinitely many premises

Tags: logic, provability

I tried to look up for a rule of inference using infinitely many premises but couldn’t find one. Why there is no such a rule? Will such a rule make any sense?

Comment: You may be interested in **infinitary logic** or the **$\omega$-rule**.

Comment: Look up "axiom schema." Not so much an axiom as a template for creating legitimate instances of axioms as required. See for example the ZFC Axiom schema of Specification (subsets) at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification There, you effectively get a new axiom for any selection criteria you may require.